# How to reply properly with Tweepy?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I am developing a bot for learning purposes, that replies a meme answer to everyone who types 'good morning' in Portuguese.

However, I cannot seem to reply in the OPs Tweet, only in my feed, using the @ of the OP, which is not as intended. Here's the code:

```
    import tweepy
    import time
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('xxxx', 'xxxxx')
    auth.set_access_token('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx')
    
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    user = api.me()
    search = 'bom dia'
    numerotweets = 50
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numerotweets):
    try:
            bomdia =  "example, " "@" + tweet.user.screen_name + " example"
            status = api.get_status(tweet)
            api.update_status(status = bomdia, in_reply_status_id = status.id, auto_populate_reply_metadata=True)
    print('bom dia com sucesso')
            tweet.favorite()
            time.sleep(120)
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    print(e.reason)
            time.sleep(5)
    break
    except StopIteration:
    break
```

I´ve tried with `in_reply_status_id = tweet.id`, but it also did not work. Sometimes I get error 431; sometimes it doesn't find any Tweet.

Comment: Print `bombia` to ensure it has the right result. Also, why do `status = api.get_status(tweet)` just to get its `id`? You can get it from the `tweet` object and use it as `in_reply_status_id=tweet.id`.

Comment: I tried that also, but it comments only on my feed, it does not reply in the users tweet.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for [`API.update_status`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#API.update_status) and the [POST statuses/update](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update) endpoint it uses is `in_reply_to_status_id`, not `in_reply_status_id`.